# How to fix "MobaXterm X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol"

Tags: x11-forwarding, x-server, mobaxterm, xauth

When connecting from Windows to my Linux box using MobaXterm, I cannot open Linux-GUI applications on the Windows side. On the Windows side, nothing happens. On the Linux box I get this error message:

```
MobaXterm X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
** ([program]:[processId]): WARNING **: Could not open display localhost:10.0
```

Comment: Here I describe a reproduction with precise versions of everything: https://askubuntu.com/questions/592537/can-i-access-ubuntu-from-windows-remotely/954989#954989

Answer (score 8):

In my case, the problem was a missing entry in ~/.Xautority on the Linux machine. You probably shouldn't edit the file directly, but use the commandline tool `xauth`.

Take the display name and the id from the error message and use them in the xauth command.

``````````
Could not open display localhost:10.0
                       ````````` ``
``````````

In my case it's *localhost* and *10*. To add it, use the `xauth add` command:

``````````
xauth add localhost/unix:10 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 27e035688dd89483c6fe48b2470172f5
          `````````      ``
``````````

The last hex-number is 32 characters long. You can create your own (quite) random number on the Linux shell with one of these commands:

```
mcookie

uuidgen -r | sed s/-//g

head -c 16 /dev/urandom | xxd -p
```

You can check, what has been added by command `xauth list`.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem running `firefox`. It turns out that I had the snap version installed (according to `which firefox`). I installed the `apt` version with

```sh
sudo apt install firefox
```

and now `firefox` launches Firefox over MobaXterm just fine.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR version:
type:

```
xauth add :0 . `mcookie`
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error. Turned out that the disk quotum of the user reached it's end and there was no space left for the .Xauthority file.