# Why do only some applications generate "MobaXterm X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol" error?

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding, mobaxterm

This question is related to [How to fix "MobaXterm X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol"](https://superuser.com/questions/1111900/how-to-fix-mobaxterm-x11-proxy-unsupported-authorisation-protocol), but the answer there did not work for me.

I use MobaXterm to ssh from a Windows PC to a Linux PC, and I know that MobaXterm has a X11 server which allows GUI applications spawned in the Linux environment to appear in the Windows environment (sorry if my terminology is clunky).

I want to run `baobab` because I want to analyze disk space hogs. I guess I need to run `sudo baobab` because otherwise `baobab` reports permission errors and isn't useful.

**Problem/question**: if I run `baobab` the gui appears, but if I run `sudo baobab`, I get this error:

```
$ sudo baobab
[sudo] password for user:
MobaXterm X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(baobab:219372): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:54:54.003: cannot open display: localhost:10.0
```

I get the same result with `firefox` vs `sudo firefox`.

**What is the problem, and how do I work around it?**

I've already tried the `xauth add` suggestion at the linked post. Display port 10 was already listed to begin with, but I added a new entry anyway, and it didn't make any difference:

```
$ xauth list
linxbox/unix:1  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  090ae067d5c16d139a64536f9c5d758e
linxbox/unix:2  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  3e67e02956713af7560d0ecb34e159b4
linxbox/unix:12  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  473351e10715668bf13345d24835671f
linxbox/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  5f005e7a67371788e58f9a605132a3cf
linxbox.company.com:1  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  090ae02bd5676d099134536f9c5d758e
linxbox/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  988522a45f0b77bf4567ceb132f4e0d8
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solved my instance of this problem:

```
$ sudo touch /root/.Xauthority
$ sudo xauth add linuxbox/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  988522a45f0b77bf4567ceb132f4e0d8
```